# I am trying to get informatin from JSON file - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a google chrome extension. I have to take information from a JSON file which is uploaded by user. But getting the error below. How can I fix this? Thank you.

> **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**

```
let selectedFile;

document.getElementById("cust").addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
        selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        
} );

document.getElementById("send").addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(selectedFile){
        const r = fetch(selectedFile);
        r.then(response => response.json())
       
        
        }
    }
 );
```

event.target.files[0] type/value is:

```
File {name: 'customer.json', lastModified: 1672167660694, lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 27 2022 22:01:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 2558, …}
```

And here is the JSON file example:

```
[
 {
  "First Name": "John",
  "Last Name": "Doe",
  "Email": "test@test.com"
  
 },
 {
  "First Name": "John2",
  "Last Name": "Doe2",
  "Email": "test2@test.com"
 },
 {
  "First Name": "John3",
  "Last Name": "Doe3",
  "Email": "tes3t@test.com",
 }
 ]
```

This code works when I try to get JSON data from a URL.

Comment: You need to debug your code. What is the type/value of `event.target.files[0]`, for example?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks. I add it to the message.

Comment: `fetch` doesn't work with the File object. You can use selectedFile.text().then(t => JSON.parse(t)......